# Image size error while rendering UIView to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to convert two images into one image with custom design.
The expected image is a snapshot of my UICollectionViewCell, not a UIImage actually.
I copied the layout codes from my custom UICVCell.swift file and tried to render the view into UIImage, but the result image is what you can see below.

I searched through a lot of questions in SOF, but most of it was about 'How you can render a UIView into a UIImage.'
I've tried drawing too, but had the same messed up result.

Can anybody tell me what's the problem?
I would really appreciate your help, it's my first question in SOF.
I might cry in a minute or two, literally...

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
private var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    iv.clipsToBounds = true

    return iv
}()

func createBubbleImage(images: [UIImage?]) -> UIImage? {
    switch images.count {
    case 1:
        return images[0]
    case 2:
        let newView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        let size = newView.frame.width

        let iv0 = UIImageView(image: images[0])
        iv0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv0.clipsToBounds = true

        let iv1 = UIImageView(image: images[1])
        iv1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv1.clipsToBounds = true

        newView.addSubview(iv0)
        iv0.anchor(top: newView.topAnchor, left: newView.leftAnchor, paddingTop: size * 0.04, paddingLeft: size * 0.04, width: size * 0.56, height: size * 0.56)
        newView.addSubview(iv1)
        iv1.anchor(bottom: newView.bottomAnchor, right: newView.rightAnchor, paddingBottom: size * 0.04, paddingRight: size * 0.04, width: size * 0.56, height: size * 0.56)
        
        iv0.layer.cornerRadius = size * 0.28
        iv1.layer.cornerRadius = size * 0.28
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: newView.bounds)
        return renderer.image { ctx in
            newView.layer.render(in: ctx.cgContext)
        }
        
    default:
        return UIImage(named: "logo")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.center(inView: view)
    imageView.setDimensions(width: 300, height: 300)

    imageView.image = createBubbleImage(images: [UIImage(named: "0"), UIImage(named: "1")])
}
```

}

[Expected Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARXDC.jpg)
[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1OkS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Remove the code lines that have the `anchor` method.
2. Initiate the `iv0` and `iv1` with `UIImageView(frame: ...)`
3. Add `iv0.image = images[0]` and `iv1.image = images[1]`

I also increased the radius a little bit because in my test device the images were not completely circular.

The code should look like this:

```
func createBubbleImage(images: [UIImage?]) -> UIImage? {
    switch images.count {
    case 1:
        return images[0]
    case 2:
        let newView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        let size = newView.frame.width

        let iv0 = UIImageView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        iv0.image = images[0]
        iv0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv0.clipsToBounds = true

        let iv1 = UIImageView(frame: .init(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))
        iv1.image = images[1]
        iv1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv1.clipsToBounds = true

        newView.addSubview(iv0)
        newView.addSubview(iv1)

        iv0.layer.cornerRadius = size * 0.35
        iv1.layer.cornerRadius = size * 0.35

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: newView.bounds)
        return renderer.image { ctx in
            newView.layer.render(in: ctx.cgContext)
        }

    default:
        return UIImage(named: "logo")
    }
}
```

With it, the result is the following:

[image]

I had to take a screenshot from your "expected image", that's why the images look like zoomed in. You can play with the `UIImageView(frame: ...)` part to adjust the two images as you want (I didn't played enough to avoid that cut in the edges, but it is possible with the right measures).

Remark: the `x` and `y` values in the UIImageView frame are the horizontal and vertical distances from the top-left corner of `newView` to the top-left corner of your UIImageView, respectively.

Comment: Thank you, so much. I really, really appreciate your answer. It works perfectly!!! What might've been the problem, though? Since it didn't work when I set the relative layout and worked with the absolute layout, is it because the rendering was fired before layout was set?

Comment: I'm glad it worked :). I think that the problem was with the size of the images. In your approach, you assign the image and then you resize it inside the .anchor(...) method. Maybe this method resizes only the frame and not the actual image (I really don't know). In my answer, you first set the frame and then the image (in such case, the image is fitted into the frame size).

Comment: Ohh... That makes sense. Thanks for the reply, really. Have a nice day! :)